# Why does the fan cycle on and off during heating cycle only?

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace, fans, heat-pump

My neighbor has an older model Carrier heat pump with electric strip heat. Here lately after she had maintenance done the fan indoor fan that is Will occasionally cycle on and off. I went over and looked at it and sure enough it will do this occasionally for some reason the relay will will pull in the fan relay and then it will just disengage and it does this maybe four or five times and then I'll seem to go back to normal. Any ideas would be helpful?

Comment: This only occurs during heating

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]! Please [edit] your question to clarify what "after she had maintenance done the fan indoor fan that is Will occasionally cycle on and off" means. I'm sure your phone "helpfully" changed a couple of words for you. Also, please include the "heating only" comment into your question so others are sure to see it. Once you've done that, take the [tour] to get an idea of how things work here, since it's a bit different than most discussion-based fora.